# How to check a c programs's main function's return value from another c program

Tags: c, child-process, return-code

I am trying to test whether a c program has compiled and executed correctly or not.

Say I have just print **Hello World**  in a c program so I want to write a c program to check

that the first program has returned 0 or has returned something else.

How can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually platform-dependent and depends on how you run one program from another.  If you use the C library function `system`, you can run the program and then read the status code from that program as follows:

```
int returnCode = system("./hello-world-program");
if (returnCode == 0) {
     ...
}
```

However, you're usually better off using OS-level primitives to do this.  Linux uses `fork` and `exec` to handle this, and you can read the child process's exit code given the process ID number by using the [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) function in conjunction with some other code.  Windows has its own mechanism for doing this which, unfortunately, I'm not familiar with.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK I am doing in windows not in linux and when I am calling **./hello-world-program** with system calling it is giving me the following error _'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
!ok
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.047 s
Press any key to continue._ <br/>  Here are  the codes `int main(void)
{

    printf("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
` and  `int a=system("./Hello.exe");
if(a==0)
{
    printf("ok");

}else
printf("!ok");


    return 0;` <br/> Regards

Comment: Sorry, the notation `./Hello.exe` is Linux-specific.  Try removing the `./` and just writing `Hello.exe` instead.